# Not able to set background image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to set a background image, on top of which I can drag different shapes to highlight different areas in the background image.
But I am only able to see any one of it, either the shapes or the image only.
below is my code:

1) drawbackground function is responsible for drawing background image.
2) An array of 3 circle object, creates the circle and render it on the canvas.
3) Three mouse events and corresponding functions for it.

I tried passing the draw function inside drawbackground, so that the circles could be drawn upon the image. But some how, I am only able to see any one of them.
`

```js
//track mouse position on mousemove
var mousePosition;
//track state of mousedown and up
var isMouseDown;

//reference to the canvas element
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.75;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.75;
//reference to 2d context
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//add listeners
document.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setDraggable, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', setDraggable, false);

//make some circles
var c1 = new Circle(50, 50, 50,  "black");
var c2 = new Circle(200, 50, 50, "green", "black");
var c3 = new Circle(350, 50, 50, "blue", "black");
//initialise our circles
var circles = [c1, c2, c3];
drawbackground(c, ctx, draw);
draw(c, ctx);
function drawbackground(c, ctx, onload){
    var imagePaper = new Image();
    imagePaper.onload = function(){
     ctx.drawImage(imagePaper,100, 20, 500,500);
     onload(c, ctx);
    };
  imagePaper.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg";
}

//main draw method
function draw(c, ctx) {
    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    drawCircles();
}

//draw circles
function drawCircles() {
    for (var i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        circles[i].draw();
    }
}

//key track of circle focus and focused index
var focused = {
    key: 0,
    state: false
}

//circle Object
    function Circle(x, y, r, fill, stroke) {
        this.startingAngle = 0;
        this.endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;

        this.fill = fill;
        this.stroke = stroke;

        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.startingAngle, this.endAngle);
           // ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
           // ctx.fill();
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function move(e) {
        if (!isMouseDown) {
            return;
        }
        getMousePosition(e);
        //if any circle is focused
        if (focused.state) {
            circles[focused.key].x = mousePosition.x;
            circles[focused.key].y = mousePosition.y;
            draw(c, ctx);
            return;
        }
        //no circle currently focused check if circle is hovered
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            if (intersects(circles[i])) {
                circles.move(i, 0);
                focused.state = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        draw(c, ctx);
    }

    //set mousedown state
    function setDraggable(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        if (t === "mousedown") {
            isMouseDown = true;
        } else if (t === "mouseup") {
            isMouseDown = false;
            releaseFocus();
        }
    }

    function releaseFocus() {
        focused.state = false;
    }

    function getMousePosition(e) {
        var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
        mousePosition = {
            x: Math.round(e.x - rect.left),
            y: Math.round(e.y - rect.top)
        }
    }

    //detects whether the mouse cursor is between x and y relative to the radius specified
    function intersects(circle) {
        // subtract the x, y coordinates from the mouse position to get coordinates 
        // for the hotspot location and check against the area of the radius
        var areaX = mousePosition.x - circle.x;
        var areaY = mousePosition.y - circle.y;
        //return true if x^2 + y^2 <= radius squared.
        return areaX * areaX + areaY * areaY <= circle.r * circle.r;
    }

Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};
draw(c, ctx);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid red;" ></canvas>
```

`

Here is the link for the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y9fr1q7n/101/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to much unnecessary code (I left it it's up to you to make it better).

the problem was in drawbackground function because you wait for img load each time the mouse move and there was a problem in draw function to because when you clear the canvas you don't redraw the img

```js
//track mouse position on mousemove
var mousePosition;
//track state of mousedown and up
var isMouseDown;

//reference to the canvas element
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.75;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.75;
//reference to 2d context
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//add listeners
document.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setDraggable, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', setDraggable, false);

//make some circles
var c1 = new Circle(50, 50, 50,  "black");
var c2 = new Circle(200, 50, 50, "green", "black");
var c3 = new Circle(350, 50, 50, "blue", "black");
//initialise our circles
var circles = [c1, c2, c3];
var imagePaper = new Image();
imagePaper.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg";
imagePaper.onload = function(){
    draw(c, ctx);
};

function drawbackground(c, ctx, onload){
    ctx.drawImage(imagePaper,100, 20, 500,500);
}

//main draw method
function draw(c, ctx) {
    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    drawbackground(c, ctx, draw);
    drawCircles();
}

//draw circles
function drawCircles() {
    for (var i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        circles[i].draw();
    }
}

//key track of circle focus and focused index
var focused = {
    key: 0,
    state: false
}

//circle Object
    function Circle(x, y, r, fill, stroke) {
        this.startingAngle = 0;
        this.endAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;

        this.fill = fill;
        this.stroke = stroke;

        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.startingAngle, this.endAngle);
           // ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
           // ctx.fill();
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function move(e) {
        if (!isMouseDown) {
            return;
        }
        getMousePosition(e);
        //if any circle is focused
        if (focused.state) {
            circles[focused.key].x = mousePosition.x;
            circles[focused.key].y = mousePosition.y;
            draw(c, ctx);
            return;
        }
        //no circle currently focused check if circle is hovered
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            if (intersects(circles[i])) {
                circles.move(i, 0);
                focused.state = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        draw(c, ctx);
    }

    //set mousedown state
    function setDraggable(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        if (t === "mousedown") {
            isMouseDown = true;
        } else if (t === "mouseup") {
            isMouseDown = false;
            releaseFocus();
        }
    }

    function releaseFocus() {
        focused.state = false;
    }

    function getMousePosition(e) {
        var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
        mousePosition = {
            x: Math.round(e.x - rect.left),
            y: Math.round(e.y - rect.top)
        }
    }

    //detects whether the mouse cursor is between x and y relative to the radius specified
    function intersects(circle) {
        // subtract the x, y coordinates from the mouse position to get coordinates 
        // for the hotspot location and check against the area of the radius
        var areaX = mousePosition.x - circle.x;
        var areaY = mousePosition.y - circle.y;
        //return true if x^2 + y^2 <= radius squared.
        return areaX * areaX + areaY * areaY <= circle.r * circle.r;
    }

Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid red;" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the mistake. Your code worked for me , so I am marking it as the Answer. I am pretty new to canvas drawings and image processing, and have been assigned a task to make something like an image editor. I am not sure which code is unnecessary yet, but will try to make it compact and readable. I will copy the updated code here in comment section. Request you to please verify it once. Thanks.

Comment: I tried cleaning up the code to the best of my JS knowledge so far. So I removed the array, as I would only need one circle moving forward. But the circle is not responding to any mouse event. I tried debugging the code, but not able to make out what is it that I did wrong. Below id the fiddle link for the same.Could you please help me out in pointing the mistake I did here.                                                                            https://jsfiddle.net/d409kyz8/51/

Comment: you forget to do `focused.state = true` https://jsfiddle.net/d409kyz8/72/

Comment: Thank you Evgeni. Do you think I still have unnecessary code in it? I have to add a lot more functionality in it to meet the business requirement. Could you please suggest me some good ebook or tutorial where I can find things like making dynamic drag-able arrows with text, Multi-line text areas, normal arrows on image and saving the final canvas drawing into local directory as an image? whichever tutorial I am reading covers only the basic of canvas image processing. I am still a beginner in JS and currently reading https://eloquentjavascript.net/ book and some online short video tutorials.